# BigQuery current day active query only returning one app_id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using the following query to query multiple tables and datasets on my project. The first two `union all` work fine and will return what I want, the issue I'm having is that when adding more it won't add anything else to the output. I think this is coming from my `GROUP BY` but I'm not sure. Any help would be great.

The expected outcome should be multiple targets, not just one.

```
WITH allTables AS (
SELECT 
   CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
   user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
 FROM `d1.app_events_intraday_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
 WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'

 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
   CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
   user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
 FROM `d1.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
 WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'

   UNION ALL
    SELECT 
     CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
     user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
   FROM `d2.app_events_intraday_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
   WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
    BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'

   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
     CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
     user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
   FROM `d2.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
   WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
    BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
) SELECT 
   app as target,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS datapoint_value,
   UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', '20170406')) as datapoint_time
 FROM allTables
 GROUP BY app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the last piece of the query individually:

```
  SELECT 
  CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as 
    app,
          user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
          FROM `d2.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
            WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
             BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
```

Comment: Seemed to be the issue.